# Files dissappeared after remounting NTFS partition. Why?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, mount, ntfs

I was trying to login my Ubuntu 14.04, but after entering password, I wasn't able to see any icons or dash. I had faced this issue before and I knew the solution as well.
The issue was that my Ubuntu partition was almost full.

I planned to move the huge downloaded files to my Windows partition.
I got into the terminal <kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd></kbd> and mounted my Windows drive at `/mnt`.

Then I moved files using `mv` to my mounted drive.
The files were moved successfully (I confirmed that with `ls`).
I unmounted the drive and rebooted my system and what I found?
The files were vanished.

Just like that. What might be the reason?
I also tried recovering the files, but no success so far!

**EDIT :**
I was successful to recover some of the files (not all). The files appeared in the explorer as soon as I ran `chkdsk` on the affected drive.

Some files were corrupt (The clusters might have got overwritten).

Comment: Did you shut down Windows properly or did you hibernate it? If you've hibernated it, the Windows file system could be not consistent and you could damage it when mounting and modifying it.

Comment: @NZD It was properly shut down

Comment: In Ubuntu, does the Windows drive get mounted as NTFS or NTFS-3g?  Linux can't write to NTFS, only NTFS-3g.  The mount command for NTFS likely contains a umask=0222 argument to remove all write permissions.  If that's the issue, no writing took place.  (But that doesn't explain the confirmation.)

Comment: Did u check with `sudo ls /mnt` where ur ntfs partition is mounted at /mnt

Comment: @BharatG Yes, it was mounted.

Answer (score 0):

Just an hint: a **`sync`** problem

> The kernel keeps data in memory to avoid doing (relatively slow) disk
>   reads and writes.  This improves performance, but **if the computer
>   crashes, data may be lost or the file system corrupted as a result**.
>
> **The `sync' command ensures everything in memory is written to disk.**

In your case probably you turn off the computer before it ends to physically copy the files.
Unfortunately the simple `ls` answer is not enough to guarantee that the kernel finished to flush them.

Moreover if your HDD was completely full some part of the files should still be only on the memory; thus, after the system reboot, there is no way to extract again them from the *ram*.

Next time you can try to avoid this problem giving a `sync` command before to turn off and waiting its exit status:

```
mv  From_Here To_There 
sync && echo " ### DONE : sync finish to work ##"
```

**Reference**

- `info coreutils 'sync invocation'` you can read more

  > 'sync' writes any data buffered in memory out to disk.  This can
  >   include (but is not limited to) modified superblocks, modified inodes,
  >   and delayed reads and writes.  This must be implemented by the kernel;
  >   the 'sync' program does nothing but exercise the `sync' system call.

**Note**

When you unmount the partition the sync is given by the system, but you have to wait that unmount process finish correctly. If it doesn't you should have the problem you find.